# classList.add() not working in a function?

Tags: javascript, html

classList not working as expected

```
var button = document.getElementById('dropdown-trigger'),
    dropdownList = document.getElementsByClassName('dropdown-list'),

button.addEventListener('mouseover', displayDropdown);

function displayDropdown() {
  dropdownList.classList.add('none');
}
```

I keep getting in the console:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'add' of undefined

But if I  were to use classList like:

```
function displayDropdown() {
  button.classList.add('none');
}
```

It would work just fine. It seems like I can't use classlist on other elements?

Comment: check if `dropdownList = document.getElementsByClassName('dropdown-list')` is returning `[]`

Comment: In your 2 var declaration you have a `,` at the end instead of a `;`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`document.getElementsByClassName` returns a list of elements, not a single element (hence the 'element**s**'). You'll want to add the class on each of these elements. If there's only a single dropdown list, you could also give it an ID and use `getElementById` instead.

Answer (score 2):

> It seems like I cant use classlist on other elements.

You can, but not on a `NodeList` collection. You should either iterate through the collection or get a specific item from the collection.

```
dropdownList[0].classList.add('none');
```

Another option is using the `querySelector` method instead of the `getElementsByClassName`. `querySelector` function  selects the first matching element.

```
dropdownList = document.querySelector('.dropdown-list')
```